# Combine data from 2 datasets with no matching values (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on creating a file of baseball statistic leaders, but am having trouble combining the different stat leaders together into one row. Only wanting the top 5 in each category, but if multiple players have the same number of hits, for example, then there might be more than 5 rows returned (as shown in the second image)

I've tried using `ROW_NUMBER` and selecting top 5, but that excludes those instances where more than 1 person has the same number, but are still in the top 5.

My current data set is set up like below:

```
create table #Tmp 
(PlayerName varchar(10)
,AtBats int
,Hits int
)
INSERT INTO #Tmp
select 'p1', 30, null
UNION ALL SELECT 'p3', 27, null
UNION ALL SELECT 'p2', 22, null
UNION ALL SELECT 'p9', 15, null
UNION ALL SELECT 'p7', 10, null
UNION ALL SELECT 'p2', null, 15
UNION ALL SELECT 'p9', null, 12
UNION ALL SELECT 'p11', null, 9
UNION ALL SELECT 'p3', null, 8
UNION ALL SELECT 'p7', null, 5    
UNION ALL SELECT 'p1', null, 5
```

[image]

I can create 2 data sets by selecting `where AtBats is not null` and `where Hits is not null` but have nothing to match on in order to combine the rows into the desired result set of:

```
SELECT 'p1' as PlayerName_AB, 30 as AtBats, 'p2' as PlayerName_H, 15 as Hits
UNION ALL SELECT 'p3', 27, 'p1', 12
UNION ALL SELECT 'p2', 22, 'p11', 9
UNION ALL SELECT 'p9', 15, 'p3', 8
UNION ALL SELECT 'p7', 10, 'p7', 5
UNION ALL SELECT NULL, NULL, 'p1', 5
```

[image]
 
I thought that if I could accomplish this with 2 data sets, a third, 4th, etc. wouldn't be too hard to add. I was mistaken... The answer below works perfectly with 2 datasets, but not with 3. There are gaps between the 3rd dataset.

```
create table #Tmp 
(PlayerName varchar(10)
,AtBats int
,Hits int
,RunsBattedIn int
)
INSERT INTO #Tmp
select 'p1', 30, null, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p3', 27, null, null
UNION ALL SELECT 'p2', 22, null, null
UNION ALL SELECT 'p9', 15, null, null
UNION ALL SELECT 'p7', 10, null, null
UNION ALL SELECT 'p2', null, 15, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p9', null, 12, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p11', null, 9, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p3', null, 8, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p7', null, 5, NULL    
UNION ALL SELECT 'p1', null, 5, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p2', null, NULL, 10
UNION ALL SELECT 'p9', null, NULL, 9
UNION ALL SELECT 'p11', null, NULL, 8
UNION ALL SELECT 'p3', null, NULL, 7
UNION ALL SELECT 'p7', null, NULL, 6
UNION ALL SELECT 'p5', null, NULL, 6
UNION ALL SELECT 'p14', null, NULL, 6
```

EDIT 2:

```
declare @Tmp table
(PlayerName varchar(10)
,AtBats int
,Hits int
,RunsBattedIn int
)
INSERT INTO @Tmp
select 'p1', 30, null, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p3', 27, null, null
UNION ALL SELECT 'p2', 22, null, null
UNION ALL SELECT 'p9', 15, null, null
UNION ALL SELECT 'p7', 10, null, null
UNION ALL SELECT 'p2', null, 15, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p9', null, 12, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p11', null, 9, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p3', null, 8, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p7', null, 5, NULL    
UNION ALL SELECT 'p1', null, 5, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p2', null, NULL, 10
UNION ALL SELECT 'p9', null, NULL, 9
UNION ALL SELECT 'p11', null, NULL, 8
UNION ALL SELECT 'p3', null, NULL, 7
UNION ALL SELECT 'p7', null, NULL, 6
UNION ALL SELECT 'p5', null, NULL, 6
UNION ALL SELECT 'p14', null, NULL, 6



;with PlayerStats as (
    -- Roll the rows into one per player
    select PlayerName, max(atbats) as AtBats, max(hits) as Hits, max(RunsBattedIn) as RBI 
    from @Tmp
    group by PlayerName
),
Ranks as (
    -- Rank them for each stat
    select *,
        row_number() over(order by AtBats desc) as AtBatRank,
        row_number() over(order by Hits desc) as HitRank,
        row_number() over(order by RBI desc) as RBIRank
    from PlayerStats
),
RankRow as (
    -- Add a row number per rank to handle ties
    select *,
        row_number() over(partition by AtBatRank order by PlayerName) as AtBatRow,
        row_number() over(partition by HitRank order by PlayerName) as HitRow,
        row_number() over(partition by RBIRank order by PlayerName) as RBIRow
    from Ranks
),--select * from rankrow,
Top5 as (
    -- Get the full list of ranks and rows so we can line them all up
    select AtBatRank r, AtBatRow n, AtBats as ab from RankRow
    union
    select HitRank r, HitRow n, hits as h from RankRow
    union
    select RBIRank r, RBIRow n, rbi from RankRow
)
-- Final query, lining up ranks and row numbers
select distinct r,n,
case when atbat.atbats is not null then AtBat.PlayerName else null end as AtBat, AtBat.atbats,
case when hit.hits is not null then Hit.PlayerName else null end as Hit, hit.hits, 
case when rbi.rbi is not null then RBI.PlayerName else null end as RBI, rbi.rbi as rbii
from top5
left join RankRow as AtBat on AtBat.AtBatRank=r and AtBat.AtBatRow=n
left join RankRow as Hit on Hit.HitRank=r and Hit.HitRow=n
left join RankRow as RBI on RBI.RBIRank=r and RBI.RBIRow=n
--where r<=5
order by r,n
```

Comment: Is there any column can response for order?

Comment: (if possible) i'm wanting to order everything by the number value in descending order. so each data set (the atbats data set and the hits data set) should each be ordered by their respective number value DESC @D-Shih but if that's not possible, then just getting the data like showsn in pic #2 is fine, and the user can filter manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big problem is what to do with ties. In my answer here I rank the players using Rank(), then order them within the rank using row_number(), then line them all up so that ties are shown correctly, and we always get at least the top 5 ranks.

Note I'm not using dense_rank so you may see no-one for a particular rank for one or more stats.

This can be extended to however many stats you need.

Set up sample data:

```
declare @Tmp table
(PlayerName varchar(10)
,AtBats int
,Hits int
,RunsBattedIn int
)
INSERT INTO @Tmp
select 'p1', 30, null, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p3', 27, null, null
UNION ALL SELECT 'p2', 22, null, null
UNION ALL SELECT 'p9', 15, null, null
UNION ALL SELECT 'p7', 10, null, null
UNION ALL SELECT 'p2', null, 15, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p9', null, 12, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p11', null, 9, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p3', null, 8, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p7', null, 5, NULL    
UNION ALL SELECT 'p1', null, 5, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p2', null, NULL, 10
UNION ALL SELECT 'p9', null, NULL, 9
UNION ALL SELECT 'p11', null, NULL, 8
UNION ALL SELECT 'p3', null, NULL, 7
UNION ALL SELECT 'p7', null, NULL, 6
UNION ALL SELECT 'p5', null, NULL, 6
UNION ALL SELECT 'p14', null, NULL, 6
```

Here is the query

```
;with PlayerStats as (
    -- Roll the rows into one per player
    select PlayerName, max(AtBats) as AtBats, max(Hits) as Hits, max(RunsBattedIn) as RBI 
    from @Tmp
    group by PlayerName
),
Ranks as (
    -- Rank them for each stat
    select *,
        rank() over(order by AtBats desc) as AtBatRank,
        rank() over(order by Hits desc) as HitRank,
        rank() over(order by RBI desc) as RBIRank
    from PlayerStats
),
RankRow as (
    -- Add a row number per rank to handle ties
    select *,
        row_number() over(partition by AtBatRank order by PlayerName) as AtBatRow,
        row_number() over(partition by HitRank order by PlayerName) as HitRow,
        row_number() over(partition by RBIRank order by PlayerName) as RBIRow
    from Ranks
),
Top5 as (
    -- Get the full list of ranks and rows so we can line them all up
    select AtBatRank r, AtBatRow n from RankRow
    union
    select HitRank r, HitRow n from RankRow
    union
    select RBIRank r, RBIRow n from RankRow
)
-- Final query, lining up ranks and row numbers
select r, AtBat.PlayerName as AtBat, Hit.PlayerName as Hit, RBI.PlayerName as RBI
from top5
left join RankRow as AtBat on AtBat.AtBatRank=r and AtBat.AtBatRow=n
left join RankRow as Hit on Hit.HitRank=r and Hit.HitRow=n
left join RankRow as RBI on RBI.RBIRank=r and RBI.RBIRow=n
where r<=5
order by r,n
```

Here is the result:

```
r   AtBat   Hit     RBI
1   p1      p2      p2
2   p3      p9      p9
3   p2      p11     p11
4   p9      p3      p3
5   p7      p1      p14
5   NULL    p7      p5
5   NULL    NULL    p7
```

Comment: Another thing to note is that everything in the dataset has already been cleaned and only includes the top 5 values for all stats. So all data needs to be returned. The point you brought up with ties is one of the reasons RANK() won't work because not all the stats have the same ties for the rn's to match up. That being said, with a couple updates of changing RANK to ROW_NUMBER, and some case statments, I think i can make this work for what I need!

Comment: The use of left joins means that if you get a tie in say rank 3 for RBI, then the column for rank 4 for RBI would be null. This means its clear where there was a tie, which was what I was trying to show. Its of course up to you how you would want to display this. If its all row number then you wont be able to see where their might be ties, which no doubt would lead to arguments between fans! But happy if my answer points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `FULL OUTER JOIN` on row number, which create from 
`ROW_NUMBER` window function.

```
SELECT 
    t2.PlayerName,
    t2.AtBats,
    t1.PlayerName,
    t1.Hits 
FROM 
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Hits desc) rn
    FROM #Tmp
    WHERE  AtBats IS NULL
) t1 FULL OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AtBats desc) rn
    FROM #Tmp
    WHERE  Hits IS NULL
) t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=40e249cfb32f4f2ddecb1ea899cd9469)

Comment: Well that was entirely too simple. That works perfectly! I'll mark it as accepted once the time limit is up

Comment: @Doolius No problem glad to help

Comment: I thought additional data sets would be easy to add, but if they have more rows than the previous dataset, there are blanks where the rn's don't match up. How could I add the additional data set with 7 rows (new table added with last edit)

Comment: @Doolius Is that your expect https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a988f7ee63da8c5246bc5ff72256b3ac